# How to set base in Koa for static files?

Tags: node.js, express, koa

I have a web-app that is served from

> somedomain.com/**myapp/**

what is the best way to setup it in koa not to take in account base part (myapp/) for serving static content?

Comment: https://github.com/koajs/static

Comment: but how to set up base path('myapp/') for koa-static?I played around and did not find a solution for it. Finally, I wrote my own middleware, but it should be more simple solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use [koa-mount](https://github.com/koajs/mount) to mount koa-static middleware to a specific path, like this:

```js
app.use(mount('/some-prefix', serve('./static')));
```